# Error: object references an unsaved transient instance

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I am using Hibernate, and I got the following error:

`org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance`-`save the transient instance before flushing: db.Concern`

I created an object of the `Concern` entity, where I did the following:

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "concernId")
private Concern concern;
```

Comment: Provide your full code and stack trace which helps to solve the problem

Comment: It looks like on of the referenced object have not be persisted, provide you code

Answer (score 1):

When using Hibernate or any other JPA provider, setting `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` causes persist and update and other operations being cascaded down to child relationships.

In addition by default `@OneToOne` relationships are `FetchType.Eager`. So you can either save  `concern` explicitly or you can remove `fetch = FetchType.LAZY` from the annotation .

You are probably saving some other object when this error is thrown. So before saving that object save the `concern` object and then the other object.

Comment: but how I can save Concern entity object

Comment: Since concern is still transient, and assuming the session is not closed yet, you can use `session.saveOrUpdate(concern);` after instantiating the concern object.